# Connect selendroid with Genymotion

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver

I have been working using selendroid to test android app. Code is running fine but thing is default android virtual devices are too slow.

So I would like to call genymotion virtual device instead of default android virtual device.I have installed genymotion , configure with eclipse also. But not able to call it when run my selendroid program.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution , I have installed following :

1 - Genymotion plugin for eclipse

2 - Installed "gapps-jb-20130813-signed" to genymotion virtual device.

3 - Installed "Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1" to genymotion virtual device.

Now everything working fine.